# AJAX JSON locking browser

Tags: php, json, google-chrome, browser, locking

**SERVER SIDE PHP SCRIPT**

```
echo " ";
while(connection_aborted()==0) {
    sleep(10);
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE JQuery Code (working fine)**

```
$.post("/url/to/server", some_data, function (d) {
    console.log(d);
})
```

**CLIENT SIDE JQuery Code (causing problems)**

```
$.post("/url/to/server", some_data, function (d) {
    console.log($.parseJSON(d));
})
```

When I run the first JQuery code, and refresh the browser, everything works as expected (the browser reloads). When the run the second JQuery code (notice the parseJSON), and try to refresh the browser, the browser gets locked (Chrome), it never reloads. The jquery post is causing this lock, but I don't understand why? Why is the parseJSON inside the callback function causing the browser to lock. Any work arounds for this?

FYI: The code above is just a small version of what I'm actually coding, in my real code I pass on real JSON data from the server side, and I handle it using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
$.post("/url/to/server", some_data, function (d) {
    console.log(d);
}, "json");
```

In case it is still not working we need the sample of your JSON.

Comment: tried that too, same results as having $.parseJSON inside the function. The browser doesn't refresh at all!

Comment: JSON sample:  {"connected_users":1,"image":{"append_images":[{"image_id":"65106","url":"http:\/\/a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/s2048x2048\/392472_10150740932392622_143076282621_9409919_12445871_n.jpg"}, ..................{"image_id":"65107","url":"http:\/\/a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash3\/s2048x2048\/559516_391927920841880_184289921605682_1308515_1885941461_n.jpg"}],"current_image_id":"65109"}}

Comment: it's not invalid, the "....", i just put that there because there's 600 character limit to post comments. JSON is produced by php json_encode, there's no way it can be invalid

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seems to be any valid reason why `$.parseJSON` will block/lock your browser forever. What exactly is variable `"d"` you are receiving and what is it's size?

Also you must go to:

```
Chrome --> Right click --> Inspect element --> 
Profiles --> Collect Javascript CPU Profile
```

to check and see what exactly is going wrong on the browser side.

Comment: size is very small, literally like few KB. I did some testing on PHP side, when I click "refresh" on the browser, connection_aborted() still is returning "0", meaning the connection is kept alive. Why, i don't understand?

Comment: Your json is nothing in size and shouldn't be a problem. So i suspect it can probably be a server side php script issue. But then you say without $.parseJSON everything works as if GOD made it for you. Something looks weird here, which is still hidden from us :)

Comment: I'm using sleep for a good reason, I won't get into that though. connection_aborted() returns "1" when i refresh the page. but when I have paseJSON, the PHP script keeps running.

Comment: believe it or not, thats all it is! I've been programming for a very long time to make a small mistake. but this... has gotten me! There are posts on the internet about long-polling AJAX locking the browser, but I haven't seem any post that's this weird!

Comment: well i went to this php manual (i haven't really used connection_abort() the way you are).... In the very first comment a user point out to throw `echo "<br>" ; // To make this work on chrome` ... He also states that with output buffer methods you need to include this to get this working on chrome. I have zero experience with this tip/trick but you should definitely head to this page once... http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Comment: do update this thread as and when you are at the right solution

Comment: yep, did that, as u see in my PHP code, echo " " is the first thing. You don't have to echo out "<br>" exactly, just need to echo out something. This is common, and I've taken care of it. Will post a work around if I find one, I doubt I will find the true reason for why this is happening.

Comment: does this happens only on chrome or also on mozilla and other browsers?

Comment: also in Firefox. Turns out PHP connection_aborted() function is not working. PHP has no clue when the browser was closed and the connection was disconnected. This causes the script to run on forever (never ends), and this builds up as I run more and more calls to the page. I believe PHP only allows one connection per session, so when I reload the page, PHP think "o wait, I already have a script running from this session, I'll wait for it to end before I take care of this second http request" ....but it never ends.

Comment: I still don't understand what json_parsing has anything to do with this! bummer..

Comment: as i said, i have never used connection_aborted() as you have tried too. I am not even sure how good this function actually works. There are better ways of doing such thing. Also i don't understand after `echo " ";` why do you end up checking whether client has closed the connection. Simply exit the php script after `echo` and things should work fine automatically. (i have no clue from just 6 line of code above how $.parseJSON can block the browser)

Comment: it's long polling, not sure if you are familiar with it?

Comment: well i m quite familiar with long-polling, comet, ajax, xmpp, push kind of technologies, but this is not how i will implement long-polling.

Comment: what am I doing wrong then? whats the best way to implement long polling? I need the browser to pick up on "commands" sent to it from the server. These commands are initiated by the user, so the commands can come in once a second, or one a hour. I need a very very quick way for the browser to pick up on the command.

Comment: so, i did some quick research, i downloaded the ajax based comet script from here: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start, worked fine! but... i added "sesson_start()" to the beginning of the php file, and.... it stopped working! At this point, I give up, just gonna find a way to do this without sessions! That's my workaround for now.